# Is $( \mathbb{ Z}_{10}^{*},\cdot) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_5^{*},\cdot), n\pmod {10} \mapsto n \pmod 5 $ well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is $( \mathbb{ Z}_{10}^{*},\cdot) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_5^{*},\cdot), n\pmod {10} \mapsto n \pmod 5 $ well-defined?

So what I think is that it is not because the odd multiples of 5 in $\mathbb{ Z}_{10}^{*}$ map to the class of $5\equiv0$ which is the only class taken out of $\mathbb{Z}_5$ to yield $\mathbb{Z}_5^{*}$, and  since not all elements in the domain are being mapped, then it is not a mapping, ie it is not well-defined(in a mapping all elements of the first set must be part of the domain)

What do you think? Feel free to elaborate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question you need to ask to determine whether the map is well defined is whether the following always holds for $x, y \in \Bbb Z_{10}^*$:

$$x \equiv y \pmod{10} \Rightarrow x \equiv y \pmod{5}.$$

And that's obviously true:  $x \equiv y \pmod{10} \Rightarrow 10 \mid y-x \Rightarrow 5 \mid y-x \Rightarrow x \equiv y \pmod{5}$.

And it's also clearly true that $x \in Z_{10}^* \iff (x, 10)=1 \Rightarrow (x, 5)=1 \iff x \in Z_5^*.$

The map is therefore well defined.

Now whether the map is a homomorphism is an entirely separate question.

Comment: according to the definition of map i've been given : $A \rightarrow B: y=f(x)$ is a map if $\forall x \in A \exists!  y \in B$, so all of A must be involved. so this is part of the well-definiteness, isn't it? or I've been given a unsual definition?

Comment: And the conditions I've given you test exactly that.  The first question tests uniqueness (if you choose two different names for the same element of $\Bbb Z_{10}^*$, does the map send both names to the same element of $\Bbb Z_5^*$) and the second tests existence (does your map end up in $\Bbb Z_5^*$ as required)..

Comment: Yeah, but there is class that is not being mapped :$ \{5,15,25..... \} $they are $[5]_{10}$ .They should be mapped to $ [5]_5=[0]_5 $but this class is not in $\mathbb{Z_5^*}$, the $*$ means the$ [0]_5$ has been taken out of $\mathbb{Z_5}$. Therefore the map is undefined for this class , so is it not well-defined

Comment: But $5$ is not relatively prime to $10$, so $5 \notin \Bbb Z_{10}^*$.  Also, for the same reason, $0 \notin \Bbb Z_5^*,$ but even if it were, that wouldn't matter.  A map can be well defined without being surjective (i.e., onto).  Ah.  Now I see the disconnect.  The * doesn't just remove $0$.  It limits the group to elements that are relatively prime to the modulo.  That's the only reason that $\cdot$ gives you a group operation.

Comment: isn't $\mathbb{Z_{10}^*}=\mathbb{Z_{10}}\setminus[0]_10$ just like $\mathbb{Z^*}=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Sorry I looked everywhere and couldn't find a definition of $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$. Although I saw in some post they just removed $[0]$

Comment: why having 5 makes the set not a group? the operation is closed, assocciative,.... is the inverse failing?

Comment: Exactly.  The only elements that have multiplicative inverses in $\Bbb Z_n$ are those that are relatively prime to $n$.