# Is $( \mathbb{ Z}^*,\cdot) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_5^{*},\cdot), n \mapsto n \pmod 5 $ well-defined?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is $( \mathbb{ Z}^*,\cdot) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_5^{*},\cdot), n \mapsto n \pmod 5 $ well-defined?

So what I think is that it is not well -defined because the non-zero multiples of 5 in $\mathbb{ Z}^*$ map to  $[0]_5$ but  $[0]_5 \notin \mathbb{Z_5^*}$

What do you think?

Comment: I am considering groups.

Comment: We haven't studied monoids, just groups and fields, does it change the answer?

Comment: And compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724268/is-mathbb-z-10-cdot-rightarrow-mathbbz-5-cdot-n-pmod).

Comment: If you remove the multiples of $5$ out of $\mathbb Z$ , or take $\mathbb Z_5$, the map becomes well-defined. But as written down, it is not as already mentioned.

Comment: @ Peter If I take $\mathbb{Z}_5$ where in the domain or in the codomain? I guess you meant in the codomain, instead of $\mathbb{Z}_5^*$

Comment: instead of $\mathbb Z_5^*$

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Clarify what $\mathbb Z^*$ means here. I assume $\mathbb Z $\{$0$}

Comment: @freakish  with $\mathbb{Z}^∗=\{−1,1\}$ you are referring the generated group, right?. Haven't seen that notation, I use "< >". Is that standard notation? It gets confused with the set notation

Comment: @J.C.VegaO No, I'm referring to the literal set. $\mathbb{Z}^*$ is the set with two elements: $-1$ and $1$ and with multiplication as a group operation.

Comment: @Peter I am assuming that, too. What else could it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to think that $\mathbb{Z}^*=\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$. That would be a rather uncommon notation and it is likely to be wrong. At least in pure algebra.

Given a unital ring $R$, typically $R^*$ denotes the group of all invertible elements of $R$:

$$R^*=\big\{x\in R\ \big|\ xy=yx=1\text{ for some }y\in R\big\}$$

which is a group under multiplication inherited from $R$. Note that $0\not\in R^*$ unless $R$ is a trivial (one element) ring. And so $R^*\subseteq R\backslash\{0\}$, but $R^*$ may and often is a proper subset of $R\backslash\{0\}$. In fact $R^*=R\backslash\{0\}$ if and only if $R$ is a division ring (or field in commutative case). So for example $\mathbb{Z}_5^*$ is equal to $\mathbb{Z}_5\backslash\{0\}$, but only because $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field.

But $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a division ring and in fact $\mathbb{Z}^*=\{-1,1\}$. It is literally the set containing two elements: $-1$ and $1$, no other integer is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}$. So multiplicies of $5$ are not even in $\mathbb{Z}^*$. You can easily verify that with this $n\mapsto n\text{ mod }5$ is a well defined group homomorphism.

In fact if $f:R\to S$ is any unital ring homomorphism, then it induces a group homomorphism $f^*:R^*\to S^*$ given by $f^*(x)=f(x)$. We can apply this to the well known unital ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}_m$, $n\mapsto n\text{ mod }m$.

**Edit:** Unless you actually do define $\mathbb{Z}^*$ as $\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$. In that case your reasoning is correct and this is not a well defined function.

Comment: So when you want to denote the non-zero integers you just use$ \mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$? outside group theory, in standard algebra or calculus,they used the uncommon notation a lot, so it didn't crossed my mind it could mean something else

Comment: @J.C.VegaO Are you sure you've seen $\mathbb{Z}^*=\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ notation anywhere? Cause I don't recall a single place. I might be wrong though. And yes, typically you would write $\mathbb{Z}\backslash\{0\}$ for non-zero integers.

Comment: It says on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer that
_Some authors use Z* for non-zero integers, others use it for non-negative integers, or for {–1, 1}._

Comment: @PawełCzyż it says so, although I've never seen those other definitions in papers/books. The "non-negative integers" (why not naturals?) is especially weird. But even if there are such authors then (1) I still believe this is uncommon and (2) it doesn't fit the context of the question. Which I assume was given by someone else to the OP. Unless the question is deliberately constructed in such a way that it is supposed to be tricky and fail. That would be sad.

Comment: I've seen this notation several times, including $\mathbb N^*, \mathbb Z^*$ and $\mathbb Q^*$